# How do I use class name of a generic as a string value of resulting type

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to create a type for some serialised representation of an object that includes class name as a string value.

Essentially I'm trying to have something like this:

```js
interface Serialised<T> {
    className: nameof T; // error
    value: T;
}
```

Now, of course there is no `nameof` in TypeScript. So, currently I'm using basic type description and then some typecasting later:

```js
interface Serialised {
    className: string;
    value: object;
}
```

So there's a question, or more specifically 3 of them:

1. Is there a generic solution that can be applied to any class?
2. Is there a generic solution that can be applied to any descendant of some base class?
3. Is there a solution that can be applied to a predefined set of classes? Via enums maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ability to extract the name of a class in typescript.

The best we can do is requires any serailizable  class to have a static field named `className` (or some other name) that we can extract using a type query:

```
interface SerializableClass {
    new (...a:any[]): any;
    readonly className: string;
}
interface Serialised<T extends SerializableClass> {
    className: T['className']; // error
    value: InstanceType<T>;
}

class Ok { 
    static readonly className = "Ok"
}

let o: Serialised<typeof Ok> = {
    className: "Ok",
    value: new Ok()
}

let o2: Serialised<typeof Ok> = {
    className: "Okk", //err
    value: new Ok()
}

class Bad{}
let o3: Serialised<typeof Bad> //err Type 'typeof Bad' does not satisfy the constraint 'SerializableClass'.
```